# Why does jQuery have two versions?

Tags: jquery

[On jQuery's homepage](http://jquery.com/) there's a download link referencing to two versions: `1.10.2` and `2.0.3` - why this separation?

Comment: Because they have different features and `2.0.3` isn't compatible with `1.10.2` and they don't want to force people over on a new framework just because they want an updated version of jQuery?

Comment: Look at this link, I think it will answer your question: http://jquery.com/download/

Comment: OP should google it rather than SO..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery 2.0 does not support IE8 and older anymore, therefore they could clean up the code. Since some still need support for IE8 (or older) they use 1.10

More info on http://blog.jquery.com/2013/04/18/jquery-2-0-released/

They say:

> As promised, this version leaves behind the older Internet Explorer 6,
>   7, and 8 browsers. In return it is smaller, faster, and can be used in
>   JavaScript environments where the code needed for old-IE compatibility
>   often causes problems of its own. But don’t worry, the jQuery team
>   still supports the 1.x branch which does run on IE 6/7/8. You can (and
>   should) continue to use jQuery 1.9 (and the upcoming 1.10) on web
>   sites that need to accommodate older browsers.

Answer (score 2):

Because, as with a lot of software, breaking changes were introduced in 2.0, and if you have a lot of code written against 1.0 which does not work on 2.0, you'd be pretty miffed if 1.0 was suddenly pulled completely. Hence they keep it around for a while. That's not unique to just jQuery, many projects do something like this.